# Where can I download GCC 4.3.2 binaries for Windows?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have to write a c++ program, and i want to do this in vstudio 2010, because it's the most comfortable way for me. But later this code will be compiled in gcc 4.3.2 (ejudge). I can't find gcc 4.3.2 binaries for Windows, if there any ways to check correctness of gcc compilation? Or maybe anyone will help to find gcc binaries? I found this link http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download but there i can't find 4.3.2 version binaries, only source code. Thanks.

Comment: What is your programming related question?

Comment: edit in VS, compile with gcc. You can try mingW or gcc in cygwin

Comment: @harper: asking about a compiler seems pretty programming-related to me, even if it's not a question about code.

Comment: @DanPuzey I commented the original question. CodyGrays edit improved it.

Comment: He only changed the title and tags.  Did you comment without reading the body?

Comment: I changed the title because it sounded like people weren't understanding what was really being asked. It was directly in response to harper's comment. I've seen too many questions closed recently because people don't bother to read the body, just the title. It's hard to write a good title, and lots of people don't give it much effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MinGW](http://mingw.org/), or Minimalist GNU for Windows, is a set of GNU compilers for Windows platforms. It's the easiest way to use G++ on windows platform. You could also use Cygwin, but it would be a bit of overkill.

Comment: So mingw 4.3.2 version is analogue of gcc 4.3.2?

Comment: Yes. But if you want to ensure that your code works *on Linux* with GCC, then you'll have to build it *on Linux* with GCC.

Comment: "It's highly recommended that you use the latest version of MinGW. Older versions may have more bugs and can be more difficult to install or use than the latest version" + jalf is right. You will have more or less hint if the code is portable to gcc or not; no 100% guarantee.

Comment: Is it possible that latest versions of mingw supports newer c++ standard C++11, while gcc 4.3.2 doesn't?

Comment: Only if you specify `--std=c++0x` or something like that

Comment: Ok then i will use version mingw 4.7.0, hope it will be less or more like gcc 4.3.2

Comment: Certainly more 4.3.2 than vs10-cl.exe is.

Comment: Why bother compiling and testing with 4.7 when your target is definitely 4.3.2?

Comment: A better way, in accodrance with jalf's hint, would be to set up a virtual machine, install a Linux OS and install GCC 4.3.2 there.

Comment: Looks like the closest you can get with MinGW is 4.3.0: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version4/Previous%20Testing_%20gcc-4.3.0-20080502-mingw32-alpha/

Or, you can use a Linux VM and build GCC 4.3.2 from source: http://mirrors-us.seosue.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.3.2/

Answer (score 0):

*As I recall* g++ 4.3.2 was used in an older version of the Code::Blocks IDE, as the bundled compiler.

However, I'm currently unable to connect to [http://www.codeblocks.org], so I don't know if they provide downloads of older versions.